# Ms access ranking top three

Tags: sql, ms-access, ranking

for the last few hours I have been stuck on how I can find and rank top three students and state their position. So, there is a table with fields student name and their marks. I want to use a query to find the top three students with the highest mark and assign their position, i.e. First, Second and Third. How may I do this?

edit: Also I need to find the top students in a particular class, for example the 5th grade. This info is also located on the same table on a different field.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign ranks using a correlated subquery:

```
select top 3 m.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from marks m2
        where m2.mark > m.mark
       ) as ranking
from marks m
order by mark desc;
```

Note this does a ranking equivalent to the `rank()` function in ANSI SQL.  So, if there are three ties for first place, the ranks are 1, 1, 1, 4.

Doing a dense rank would use `count(distinct)`, which MS Access doesn't support.  Perhaps this works:

```
select top 3 m.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from (select distinct mark
              from marks m2
              where m2.mark > m.mark
             ) as m
       ) as ranking
from marks m
order by mark desc;
```

Comment: Sorry, there was another thing I forgot to add, For example there are different classes and I want to rank the student from a particular class, for example, 5th grade. Then what should I do?

Comment: Also what if I want a ranking like 1,1,2

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 3 name, mark,
    CASE WHEN mark = (SELECT TOP 1 mark FROM marks ORDER BY mark DESC, name)
         THEN "First"
         WHEN mark = (SELECT MIN(t.mark) FROM (SELECT TOP 2 mark FROM marks ORDER BY mark DESC, name) t)
         THEN "Second"
         ELSE "Third"
    END AS Position
FROM marks
ORDER BY mark DESC, name
```

Note that this solution won't scale nicely if, for example, you wanted to get the top 10 ranking students (instead of 3).  In this case, an approach such as the one given by @Gordon is a better way to go.